# xamarin mvvm - detect changing text from vm data binding in custom entry renderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I made a custom entry where the main point is to hide keyboard on focus. Everything is working excellent but there is small problem.

When I modify the binding text from my vm by `EntryText=""`, then text in my Entry disappear, but keyboard is poping up... I tested an TextChanged listener  in android project but it's not reacting when I use `EntryText = ""`

My custom entry looks like this

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry), typeof(SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer))]

namespace SkanerDetali.Droid {
 class SoftkeyboardDisabledEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer {
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs < Entry > e) {
   base.OnElementChanged(e);


   if (Control != null) {
    Control.Click += (sender, evt) => {
     new Handler().Post(delegate {
      var imm = (InputMethodManager) Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
      var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

      Console.WriteLine(result);
      Control.RequestFocus();
     });
    };

    Control.FocusChange += (sender, evt) => {
     new Handler().Post(delegate {
      try {
       var imm = (InputMethodManager) Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
       var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
       Console.WriteLine(result);
       Control.RequestFocus();
      } catch (Exception Ex) {
       Console.Write(Ex);
      }
     });
    };
   }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs propertyChangingEventArgs) {
   // Check if the view is about to get Focus

   if (propertyChangingEventArgs.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName) {
    // incase if the focus was moved from another Entry
    // Forcefully dismiss the Keyboard 
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.Control.WindowToken, 0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

an Entry in xaml:

```
<local:SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry 
                x:Name="SoftKeyboardDisabledEntry"
                Text="{Binding ReadedEAN}"
                IsVisible="True"
            />
```

the TextChanged inside android project listener is not reacitng :

```
   Control.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs ev) => {
  var imm = (InputMethodManager) Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
  var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

  Console.WriteLine(result);

                    };
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve the problem? I am struggling with this from few hours...

EDIT solution... :

I made an text changed listener in better form:

```
 Control.TextChanged += (sender, evt) = >{
    new Handler().Post(delegate {
        var imm = (InputMethodManager) Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
        var result = imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding `OnElementPropertyChanged` in custom renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Entry.Text)
        || e.PropertyName == nameof(Entry.IsFocused))
    {
        //if there is change in text or focus state - act 
        // i.e hide or show keyboard?
    }
}
```